# Android studio expected class or package

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Hello guys I am trying to acces class which works with asynctasks, but strangely i get that annoying error maybe you can help me, error shows on `serverRequest.Storenaryste();` here is the code:
................................................................................

```
uzsisakyti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Global.naryste = trukme +" "+ "rad" +" "+ kaina.getText().toString();
                naris();
            }
        });


private void naris() {
        ServerRequests serverRequest = new ServerRequests(this);
        serverRequest.Storenaryste();
    }
```

ServerRequest class :

```
public class Storenaryste extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pastas",Global.elpastas ));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("slaptazodis",Global.slaptazodis ));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("naryste",Global.naryste));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS
                    + "Naryste.php");

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams() {
            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                    CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                    CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            return httpRequestParams;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where *exactly* do you get the error? We have no context about where the first snippet of code occurs, which doesn't help...

Comment: serverRequest.Storenaryste(); serverRequest gets red hover.

Comment: Well it doesn't help that you've got a class that's *actually* called `Storenaryste` but you're trying to construct an instance of `ServerRequests`...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to start your `AsyncTask` like this:

```
ServerRequests serverRequest = new ServerRequests(this);
serverRequest.Storenaryste();
```

This seems a little strange to me, you should do like this instead:

```
new Storenaryste().execute();
```

Which should work.

Also check the docs for AsyncTask for how to use it correctly:
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: It does not work throws error that it is not enclosing class.

Comment: @ben try `new serverRequest.Storenaryste().execute();` Show more of your code if it does not work.

Comment: method is not called this way.

Answer (score 0):

Change you function to

```
    private void naris() {
         new Storenaryste().execute();
    }
```

Comment: It is not enclosing class and it does not help.